# Is there a way to recover dataframes from a workspace image saved as an RDATATMP file?

Tags: r, rstudio

While saving my workspace image to an RData file, my R session was abruptly stopped. In the folder for my working directory, I now have a file with the extension .RDataTmp. I have tried loading this file into the workspace through both RStudio's "load workspace" menu option and with the command "load" but have only received errors:

```
load("~/R/project_folder/workspace.RDataTmp")
Error in load("~/R/project_folder/workspace.RDataTmp") : 
  error reading from connection
```

In this workspace image, I have a couple dataframes I want to recover. Is there anyway to get them?

Comment: Hi hmph_, did you save the code that brought in or created the dataframes?

Comment: I did, but the code is time-contingent. It pulls data from a perpetually updating source, and can only go back so far, so I can't rerun the code. The data pulled will be different.

Comment: I don't believe it's retrievable. In the future, I would include something like `saveRDS(mydata, paste0("mydata", Sys.date()))`